# Converting binary serialization to human-readable serialization

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fread, scanf

I'm converting a program that used to do a binary dump of a struct to file and read that binary struct back in using fread. I want to convert it to creating and reading human readable data files, which of course means I need to format the data and such.

The creation of the data files in ascii went without a hitch. I switched from using fwrite to using fprintf with a format specified ending with \n for new line.

```
FPFPF = fopen( flightStr, "w+" );

    if (FPFPF != NULL)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < FlightInfo[flightnum].endFrameIndex; i++)
        {
            FlightEntries[flightnum][i].local_z += DeltaAlt;

            //if (fwrite (&FlightEntries[flightnum][i], sizeof (FLIGHT_ENTRY_TYPE), 1, FPFPF) !=1)
            if (fprintf (FPFPF, "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n",
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].local_x,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].local_y,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].local_z,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].pitch,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].roll,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].heading,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].gearpos,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].flappos,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].speedbrakepos,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].canopypos,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].afterburnerOn,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].kias,
                FlightEntries[flightnum][i].time) !=1)
            {
                WE++;
            }
        }

        fclose( FPFPF );
    }
```

This worked just fine. you can see the old fwrite is commented out now.

I was hoping that reading the file would be just as easy, but it doesn't seem to be working, and I'm unable to debug it because I have a weird memory leak with Freetype in debug builds that prevents me from stepping into this code.  Here's the code that reads from the file.

```
if (load)
        {
            for ( i = 0; i < MAX_FLIGHT_ENTRIES; i++)
            {               
                // If the file end is found before it should be, set values to defaults
                // and save the file
                if (feof(pFile))
                {
                    FlightInfo[fileIndex].endFrameIndex = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //fread (&FlightEntries[fileIndex][i], sizeof (FLIGHT_ENTRY_TYPE), 1, pFile);

                    fscanf (pFile, "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n",
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].local_x,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].local_y,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].local_z,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].pitch,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].roll,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].heading,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].gearpos,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].flappos,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].speedbrakepos,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].canopypos,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].afterburnerOn,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].kias,
                        &FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].time);
                }
            }

            FlightInfo[fileIndex].endFrameIndex = i - 1;

        }
```

There's a bit of other checking before pFile is opened and load is a bool that is set if we're going to do more than just see if a file exists. If it matters, all the values of the FlightInfo struct are float except for local_x, local_y, and local_z which are double. Is there something that stands out as obviously wrong here? It compiles and runs without error until this block of code is called, then it just crashes.

Comment: I might be wrong, but my first attempt would be to use paranthesis here: `&FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].local_x` => `&(FlightEntries[fileIndex][i].local_x)`. I always forget the evaluation order and using paranthesis can't be wrong ^^

Comment: @UniversE: Those parens are obviously superfluous.

Comment: It does not matter to `fprintf` whether they are `float` or `double` due to default-promotions, but it matters very much to `fscanf`.

Comment: I suggest using the return code from fscanf(), which is the number of fields converted, to see that you are getting exactly what you expect at runtime.

Comment: Also, the '\n` in the fscanf string doesn't do what you think it does.  It shouldn't be harmful here, but it will skip any whitespace characters it sees (not just a single newline) into the next line and up to (but not including) the next non-blank or to the end of file.

Comment: @Deduplicator the local_x, y and z are double...the rest are float. should the first three lines of the fscanf be %d?

Comment: what is the return of  `fscanf `?

Comment: You output a number of records that depend on the input `FlightInfo` element, but you (attempt to) read back a fixed number of records.  There are several ways in which that could go wrong.

Comment: @MikeHousky I was hoping using the same format string for fscanf and fprintf would make reading work the same as writing.  Also, what would I do with the return code? Just evaluate if it's 13 and die if not?

Comment: fscanf returns the number of elements stored into arguments.  It should be equal to the number of arguments you provide after the format if the entire scan succeeded.  If not, you'll get a smaller number (maybe 0) or the constant EOF if an error occurred before any field was stored.

Comment: You can use the same format-specifier for both, no trouble. `fprintf` will simply ignore that you left out the `l`-modifier for floating-point.

Comment: @MikeHousky I'm getting a return of 0 on the fscanf...I'm still not sure why...I've changed my format to "%lf,%lf,%lf,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n" and a sample line from my data file looks like this: -13219.808594,23.606647,-51761.851563,2.893528,0.589661,189.878860,1.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,9.219837,37.645699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter to `fprintf` whether you pass a `float` or a `double` due to the default promotions performed for variadic arguments.

But it matters very much for `fscanf` whether you pass a `float*` or `double*`:

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html for the flags:

> *The following type modifier characters can appear in a conversion
>          specification:*
>
> `l`      Indicates either that the conversion will be one of d, i, o,
>                 u, x, X, or n and the next pointer is a pointer to a long int
>                 or unsigned long int (rather than int), **or that the conversion
>                 will be one of e, f, or g and the next pointer is a pointer to
>                 double (rather than float)**.  Specifying two l characters is
>                 equivalent to L.  If used with %c or %s, the corresponding
>                 parameter is considered as a pointer to a wide character or
>                 wide-character string respectively.

Actually, you should read that whole man-page, there are other interesting pitfalls.

As an aside, the `l`-modifier has no effect for `fprintf` with a floating-point-specifier.

Comment: @Deduplicator I guess I don't fully understand how I would apply that to my format...is l supposed to be a number or do I add the literal l to the format string?  so should the first three be %d6, %f6, or should it be %dl or %fl?  I've never used those before...The 6 comes from how many decimal places are written in the file for each entry on each line.

Comment: Seems you should read that man-page carefully. The format is: "`%` [`*` for assignment suppression] [maximum field width] [type modifier] conversion" for `fscanf`. Perhaps you would like this reference better: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @Deduplicator From what I can tell, I should be using "%lf,%lf,%lf,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n" But it still doesn't work...I may still be missing something though...

Comment: @Deduplicator here's an example line from the data file: -13219.808594,23.606647,-51761.851563,2.893528,0.589661,189.878860,1.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,9.219837,37.645699